# Import each Excel File to a new SQL Table using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have more than 50 Excel file and i want to import each one of them to an new SQL table in SQl server with the name of the table is the name of the excel file 
How can i achieve that using SSIS ?

each file  have its own column names. so i need a way to loop over each files in the folder and get the data of each file into new sql table

Comment: This might help you:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368530/Dynamic-Excel-file-loading-with-SSIS

Comment: it's interesting but this isn't what i'm looking for

Comment: This might be a job for BIML, depending on whether it's quicker to learn BIML, or quicker to just slog through and create each data flow manually.

Answer (score 1):

This just gives you a general idea what could do.

Create a staging table in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ExcelStaging
(LineId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
, FileLine VARCHAR(2000)
, FileName VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Truncate staging table before import each of your file.

Create script task, read every line of your file and insert into staging table colume ‘FileLine’.  LineId=1 should always hold the original file column header.  You must careful choose which delimiter, comma separator or fixed width?

Once file loaded into your table, execute SQL task – a stored procedure

a.  based on the filename and  FileLine where LineID = 1, create a new SQL table. The new table may look ugly – every column data type is varcher, since don’t know advance what data type is for each field.

b.  Insert into new table select substring of FileLine as columns from staging table. Here the delimiter you choose will determine how you substring for each column.

Comment: nice idea, but i need to keep the column data type the same as Excel

Comment: Ok, you need to create the tables before importing files. By read file name and first line of file content, how are you or computer able to decide what data types are?

Comment: the import/ export wizard in SQL server can do that, my goal is to do the same thing in SSIS without creating each table manually.